# CSS only: Move the 2. item of a flexbox upwards when the width changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need your help with CSS. I have a box with 3 DIV elements. The DIV elements should keep their size and should not be changed. But when the total width changes (it must be dynamicly, for example when a sidebar goes up), I want the B-DIV element goes to the top and the A-DIV element goes down next to the C-DIV element. If the space is further reduced, the order should be B - A - C. I have tried to show this graphically:

[image]

**This is my example code that does not work!!!**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">10:00 - 10:30</div>
  <div id="b">VerrrrrrrrryLooooooongText</div>
  <div id="c">Room XY in Tower B</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Do you know what your break points are (ie how narrow does the viewport get for you to want to switch to the second layout and then again for the third layout)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally know of a way to do this without media queries - you can do something like this and manipulate the css order property:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) /* change this to suit your needs */ {
  #b {
  order: 1;
  }

  #a {
    order: 2;
  }

  #c {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```